# Recurring Payment via Paypal Express in Germany

Tags: paypal, payment

not a direct programming question, but hopefully I get support anyway: We want to integrate in a form, where we sell magazine subscription, paypal as a payment method. The plan is to implement a recurring payment, so that every year a payment is triggered.

We cannot find information about the following:

- Is this already possible in germany? (Cause older depracted docs say "no")
- Is this only possible if the customer has a credit card in his paypal account or also possible with a connected bank account?

Thanks for help
René

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a support request for PayPal, not about programming

Answer (score -1):

Well Rene, Germany are not in the list of country which can use Recurring payment. Either in NVP or REST, both are not feasible to use.